# Form within a form with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a form for an order and with this, the user have to choose a category then associated product. As I want it to be dynamic, I wrote this :

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>

    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories_list, :id, :name, :prompt => "Selectionner"  %>

    <%= render :partial => 'products' %>

    <%= f.submit 'Enregistrer', :class=>'button add'%>

<% end %>
```

_products.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for(Order.new, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <% if !@products.blank? %>
    <%= f.label 'Produit :' %><br />
    <%= f.select :product_id, @products.collect{ |s| [s.name,s.id]}, :prompt => "Selectionner" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.label 'Produit :' %><br />
    <%= f.select :product_id, '' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in the controller :

```
def update_product_select
  @products = Product.where(:category_id=>params[:id]).order(:name) unless params[:id].blank?
  render :partial => "products", :layout => false, :locals => { :products => @products }
end
```

For the dynamic part, it works.
But when I click on the submit button, the product ID is not sent !

Can you tell me how is it possible for me to combine dynamic menu and form submitting please ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you can nest forms in HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: So, in your opinion, what is the best way for me to have dynamic menu in a form ?

Comment: I think @mathiewgagne's questinos are good.  What is the workflow you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Would the gem nested_form by Ryan bates not help here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need two forms. Something is wrong here.

Explain a bit more on the workflow if possible.

I see you should either make use of `fields_for` if you are trying to edit other associated instances of @order.

For a dynamic menu, have a javascript event binding on the category that updates the products list based on the category. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: In fact I took exemple from here : http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/  but whitout using formstatic, is it the reason ? I will be happy to see some example please

Comment: The example is 3 years old. I doubt it's because you're not using formstatic. And for the example, you actually have the necessary jQuery in your tutorial, which is still valid.

Comment: For the workflow : I have a table with product, which is linked to categories (belongs_to / has_many). I want user in my order form, to choose a category and then the product (product belongs_to order). I want it dynamic because it is easier for the user to choose it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised
It needs a subscription, but you can also see the previous episode to get an idea if you dont want to subscribe.